# Passing the value of page from Pagination.jsx to App.jsx

Tags: reactjs, api

While I'm trying to get in to React, I started a project and got stuck. Maybe some one can help me to find the issue. Bellow I explain what the app should do.

The user types a query in an input-box inside **SearchBar.jsx**
The SearchBar component passes the **query** to **App.jsx** and fires up fetchPhotos function, which starts an API request.

To sort out pagination, the App.jsx imports **Pagination.jsx**, which calculates the number of pictures in the response and displays pagination buttons.

**The above works.**

But now if you click on a pagination button, the value for **page** from Pagination component should be passed to App.jsx and so to fetchPhotos function (runs the API request).

I guess the problem is that the value of **page** never finds its way to App.jsx and so the API request is missing the value of page.

I spent hours but couldn't find a way to fix it, due to lack of knowledge. Could you please point me to the right direction and show me what is wrong with the code?

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Pagination from "../Pagination";
import SearchBar from "../SearchBar";
import ListItem from "../ListItem";
import "./app.scss";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    photos: [],
    totalPhotos: 0,
    perPage: 30,
    currentPage: 1,
    query: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchPhotos("gorilla", this.state.currentPage);
  }

  fetchPhotos = (inputValue, page) => {
    const baseUrl = "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos";

    const options = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Client-ID ${process.env.REACT_APP_UNSPLASH_API_KEY}`
      },
      params: {
        query: inputValue,
        page: this.state.page,
        per_page: this.state.perPage
      }
    };

    axios
      .get(baseUrl, options)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          photos: response.data.results,
          totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
          currentPage: page,
          query: inputValue
        });

      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("Error");
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <SearchBar onSubmit={this.fetchPhotos} />
        <Pagination
          current={this.state.currentPage}
          total={this.state.totalPhotos}
          perPage={this.state.perPage}
          query={this.state.query}
          onPageChanged={query => this.fetchPhotos(this.state.query)}
        />
        <List data={this.state.photos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const List = ({ data }) => {
  var items = data.map(photo => <ListItem key={photo.id} photo={photo} />);
  return <div className="grid">{items}</div>;
};

export default App;
```

**SearchBar.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class SearchBar extends Component {
  state = {
    inputValue: ""
  };

  handleFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state.inputValue);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <h1>Search for images on Unsplash</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} className="ui form">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Type here to search for images"
            value={this.state.inputValue}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value })}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default SearchBar;

**Pagination.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Pagination extends Component {
  pages() {
    var pages = [];
    for (var i = this.rangeStart(); i <= this.rangeEnd(); i++) {
      pages.push(i);
    }
    return pages;
  }

  rangeStart() {
    var start = this.props.current - this.props.pageRange;
    return start > 0 ? start : 1;
  }

  rangeEnd() {
    var end = this.props.current + this.props.pageRange;
    var totalPages = this.totalPages();
    return end < totalPages ? end : totalPages;
  }

  totalPages() {
    return Math.ceil(this.props.total / this.props.perPage);
  }

  nextPage() {
    return this.props.current + 1;
  }

  prevPage() {
    return this.props.current - 1;
  }

  hasFirst() {
    return this.rangeStart() !== 1;
  }

  hasLast() {
    return this.rangeEnd() < this.totalPages();
  }

  hasPrev() {
    return this.props.current > 1;
  }

  hasNext() {
    return this.props.current < this.totalPages();
  }

  changePage(page) {
    this.props.onPageChanged(page);
    console.log("Page inside Pagination", page);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="pagination">
        <div className="pagination__left">
          <span
            role="button"
            className={!this.hasPrev() ? "hidden" : ""}
            onClick={e => this.changePage(this.prevPage())}
          >
            Prev
          </span>
        </div>

        <div className="pagination__mid">
          <ul>
            <li className={!this.hasFirst() ? "hidden" : ""}>
              <span role="button" onClick={e => this.changePage(1)}>
                1
              </span>
            </li>
            <li className={!this.hasFirst() ? "hidden" : ""}>...</li>
            {this.pages().map((page, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index}>
                  <span
                    role="button"
                    onClick={e => this.changePage(page)}
                    className={this.props.current === page ? "current" : ""}
                  >
                    {page}
                  </span>
                </li>
              );
            })}
            <li className={!this.hasLast() ? "hidden" : ""}>...</li>
            <li className={!this.hasLast() ? "hidden" : ""}>
              <span
                role="button"
                onClick={e => this.changePage(this.totalPages())}
              >
                {this.totalPages()}
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div className="pagination__right">
          <span
            className={!this.hasNext() ? "hidden" : ""}
            onClick={e => this.changePage(this.nextPage())}
          >
            Next
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Pagination.defaultProps = {
  pageRange: 2
};

export default Pagination;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error is at `onChange', because you are giving current state query to fetch instead of the new query:

```
onPageChanged={query => this.fetchPhotos(this.state.query)}
```

You should replace it for new query like:

```
onPageChanged={query => this.fetchPhotos(query)}
```

EDIT 1:

You can see working it on https://codesandbox.io/s/9ymjj8ko9p?fontsize=14.

The changes is just as I said, on App.jsx:

1. params fixed passing page from function params and not from
2. fix onPageChange prop to Pagination like:

   ```
   onPageChanged={page => this.fetchPhotos(this.state.query, page)}
   ```

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much @Cespejo.